# Error when implementing Soft Delete in EF (Map was called more than once for type)

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, ef-fluent-api, soft-delete

i trying to implement soft delete in Entity Framework

I have this code in **OnModelCreating**

```
    if (modelBuilder == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
    }

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

    EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser> table = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

    table.Property((ApplicationUser u) => u.UserName).IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany((ApplicationUser u) => u.Roles);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey((IdentityUserRole r) => new { UserId = r.UserId, RoleId = r.RoleId }).ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany((ApplicationUser u) => u.Groups);

    EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUserGroup> usergroup = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserGroup>().ToTable("ApplicationUserGroups");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasMany((Group g) => g.Roles);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRoleGroup>().HasKey((ApplicationRoleGroup gr) => new { RoleId = gr.RoleId, GroupId = gr.GroupId }).ToTable("ApplicationRoleGroups");

    EntityTypeConfiguration<Group> groupsConfig = modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().ToTable("Groups");
    groupsConfig.Property((Group r) => r.Name).IsRequired();

    EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin> entityTypeConfiguration =
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey((IdentityUserLogin l) => new { UserId = l.UserId, LoginProvider = l.LoginProvider, ProviderKey = l.ProviderKey }).ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");

    entityTypeConfiguration.HasRequired((IdentityUserLogin u) => u.User);
    EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserClaim> table1 = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
    table1.HasRequired((IdentityUserClaim u) => u.User);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

    EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRole> entityTypeConfiguration1 = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");
    entityTypeConfiguration1.Property((ApplicationRole r) => r.Name).IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false)).Ignore(m => m.IsDeleted);

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

when i try to Migrate that to Database it gives me this error

> Map was called more than once for type 'Group' and at least one of the
>   calls didn't specify the target table name.

this error only occurs when i add this Line of code to **OnModelCreating**

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false)).Ignore(m => m.IsDeleted);
```

Any Solution for that, i need to do that to get only the rows which are (***!Is.Deleted***)

this scenario will be for most of my Models,

Please Advice,

Comment: Might be because you have multiple `.Entity<Group>` calls. Could you combine them?

Comment: @HristoYankov how to do that ?

Comment: Chain them together, but I am not sure which goes after which, without firing up VS, which I can do later today.

Comment: @HristoYankov Thanks, can you just give me hint or some similar solution